# Symfony2 - Call to undefined method FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I was able to integrate FOSUserBundle and update db schema. However, when I go to the registration path (/registration) as I have specified on my routing file, it shows me this:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User::setEnabled() in /var/www/project-symfony/projectSymfony/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php line 44.
```

Here is my main User class (user.php) located under MyProject/UserBundle/Entity

```
 <?php
namespace MyProject\UserBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as AbstractUser;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mydb_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingTestUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingTestBalances = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->actualDeviceUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingAidUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->questionnaireUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->audiograms = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * To string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    protected $password;
```

This is my config.yml file:

```
   imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.pdo
    fragments:       ~

services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            dsn:      "mysql:dbname=%database_name%"
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%

    session.handler.pdo:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: [@pdo, %pdo.db_options%]

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        mapping_types:
            enum: string
            set: string
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

# SncRedis Configuration
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
        commands:
            type: predis
            alias: commands
            dsn: redis://localhost/1
        responses:
            type: predis
            alias: responses
            dsn: redis://localhost/2
        sides:
            type: predis
            alias: sides
            dsn: redis://localhost/3
        programs:
            type: predis
            alias: programs
            dsn: redis://localhost/4
        fitting_commands:
            type: predis
            alias: fitting_commands
            dsn: redis://localhost/5
        fitting_responses:
            type: predis
            alias: fitting_responses
            dsn: redis://localhost/6

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

And this is my user.php located under the FOSBundle/Model/User.php

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Model;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Storage agnostic user object
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Johannes M. Schmitt <schmittjoh@gmail.com>
 */
abstract class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $usernameCanonical;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $emailCanonical;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $enabled;

    /**
     * The salt to use for hashing
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * Encrypted password. Must be persisted.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * Plain password. Used for model validation. Must not be persisted.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $lastLogin;

    /**
     * Random string sent to the user email address in order to verify it
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $confirmationToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $passwordRequestedAt;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $locked;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $expired;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    protected $expiresAt;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $roles;
```

Can someone please help me to fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the AbstractUser class from FOSUserBundle. Just add "extends AbstractUser" to your class and you should be fine.

You could use your own class (not extending), but you'll have to implement some other fields, because the RegistrationController relies on them.

Your class might be rewritten as following.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\UserBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as AbstractUser;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="mydb_users")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
class User extends AbstractUser implements AdvancedUserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingTestUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingTestBalances = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->actualDeviceUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hearingAidUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->questionnaireUsers = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->audiograms = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * To string
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $salt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    protected $password;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I extended and seems to work now. The problem I face now is because I have two user classes. The one on user-bundle and the user.php file that comes with FOSUserBundle. I do have some duplicates such as $username $plainpassword $Password. And when I remove them from my own user.php file it works but it gives me SQL errors. How I can avoid this? Thanks